# Side to side comparison in mobile

Tags: page-layout

Amazon has this feature to compare most helpful positive and most helpful critical reviews side by side when viewed on a pc (not from mobiles). I assume for mobiles this is impractical because the screen ratio is opposite to a computer. Or would very narrow columns still be ok to view side by side? The view has to remain in vertical orientation for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you! It won't be a good fit for mobiles to have side-by-side columns to compare.

The [stacked table](http://www.foolproof.co.uk/thinking/making-product-comparison-work-on-mobile/) approach works really well on mobiles:

[image]

Comment: Even more so because my comparison is text based and not by numbers. Stacked table to start with

Comment: @TMOTTM number based comparison also has text labels that are required to consider :)

Comment: I actually believe that the 2 column view (from @Dipak link) works better since you have a real "side-by-side" comparison (one item on the left, other on the right) and you have more column height in case you need to display text

Comment: I tried that, makes reading very inconvenient

Comment: @TMOTTM Did you try other options from this link http://www.foolproof.co.uk/thinking/making-product-comparison-work-on-mobile/ ?